# The weird behavior of the print function in python

Tags: python, printing

I'm somewhat unsure about why the `print` function in Python prints out values in different ways. Consider the following code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np

array = np.arange(3.0, dtype=np.float32)

print ("array: ",  array)
print ("array: ",  {0: 2.0 * array})
print ("array {0}".format(2.0 * array))
```

The output is below:

```
array:  [0. 1. 2.]
array:  {0: array([0., 2., 4.], dtype=float32)}
array [0. 2. 4.]
```

The format of the second one is different from others. This one shows the data format "array" and the data type "float32" explicitly. Is this a expected behavior?

Could someone explain to me the rationale behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print` uses `str` to convert its arguments to `str`. So your first two examples are equivalent to

```
print ("array: ",  str(array))
print ("array: ",  str({0: 2.0 * array}))
```

Notice the difference, though: in the first call, `array` is the argument to `str`. In the second call, the argument is just a `dict` that *contains* an `ndarray` instance. `dict.__str__` uses `repr`, not `str`, to create a string from the values contained therein.

The third example doesn't involve any implicit calls to `str` by `print`, as `print` only receives a single `str` argument. The `format` method, though, uses `str` by default to convert one of *its* arguments to a string to include it in the format string.